# append class to current page menu li (jQuery magic line plugin)

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm using the [jQuery Magic Line plugin](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/) and want to make the line appear under the current page in the menu. The menu looks like this:

```
    <ul class="group" id="example-one">
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" >About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php" >Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="clients.php" >Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="quoterequest.php" >Request a Quote</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" >Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I've been trying to modify the top answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533668/an-automated-way-to-add-a-class-to-an-anchor-link-corresponding-to-the-current-p) but haven't gotten far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.pathname`. If pages are on the *root* directory, try the following:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
$('.group a[href='+ loc +']').parent().addClass('current_page_item')
```

*However you can use PHP for doing this.*

Comment: Pages are not in the root, but I modified your script as such: `var loc = 'http://mydomain.com' + window.location.pathname;` Still not getting any result.

Comment: @miles Okay, please post the main directory of pages, then I will modify the code. like `www.domain.com/dir/dir`

Comment: site files are in `http://milespfefferle.com/facilitytech/` is that what you meant?